# How to show standard paypal option on checkout page in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have done all the settings on woocommerce->settings to enable paypal option on checkout page but it is not showing checkout with paypal option on checkout page. It is showing only cash on delivery options. I am using woocommerce plugin in my website. Where i went wrong ? How to show paypal option on checkout page ?

Comment: Anyone have any thoughts why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0):

would you please check that did the tick mark in Enable paypal also please place your paypal email address in the right place.

Hope everything will be sound

Comment: Actually paypal option is showing for all the sellers product on checkout page except admin products